# Is there a way to choose which directory cv2 VideoWriter writes to?

Tags: opencv

I am using `VideoWriter` in `cv2` using `python`, to write some images into a video. It works, however I can only get the video to save only in the directory that contains my `.py` file. And if I concatenate `/../folder_name` with my video name (e.g. `video_name.avi`), the file is not written at all.

Is there a way for me to specify which directory I can write my video file into? Or am I only able to write it into where I can currently writing it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to give it the full path name like:

**Mac/Linux**

`'~/myloc/mydirInsideLoc/myfile'` or `'/Users/username/myloc/mydirInsideLoc/myfile'`

**Windows**

`'C:\myloc\mydirInsideLoc\myfile'`